# Some events not fired in TsaveDialog with FMX

Tags: delphi, dialog, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

I am porting a project to FMX (from VCL). I use a TSaveDialog with Filter for the file extensions, but when I change the extension the 'OnTypeChange'  event does'nt fire, but the 'OnShow' event fires !

I tried TOpenDialog with the same problem.

Some informations :

- Delphi Pro 10.3.1 (I tried Delphi 10.3.3)
- Event 'OnFolderChange' does'nt fire.
- Events 'OnClose' and 'OnShow' are OK.

Any idea ? Is there any option I missed ? Or a known bug ?
My test code : just a Form with a TButton and a TSaveDialog whith some code in the events to show if they are fired.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Controls.Presentation,
  FMX.StdCtrls, System.Classes;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    SaveDialog1: TSaveDialog;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure SaveDialog1FolderChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure SaveDialog1TypeChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure SaveDialog1Close(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.SaveDialog1Close(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Self.Caption := Self.Caption + ', Close';
end;

procedure TForm1.SaveDialog1FolderChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Self.Caption := Self.Caption + ', Folder';
end;

procedure TForm1.SaveDialog1TypeChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Self.Caption := Self.Caption + ', Change';
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Self.Caption := 'Start';
  SaveDialog1.Filter := 'Applications (*.exe)|*.EXE|Text files (*.txt)|*.TXT';
  SaveDialog1.Execute;
end;

end.
```

Thx

Comment: The appropriate course of action is to (1) sigh deeply, (2) file a bug report in Embarcadero's Jira.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the `OnFolderChange` and `OnTypeChange` events are published and assignable in the `TSaveDialog`'s Object Inspector these do nothing at all.

It is possible though to make these events work like in VCL by copying the source file `FMX.Dialogs.Win.pas` to your project folder and adding the relevant missing bits from the `Vcl.Dialogs.pas` source file, which include but not limited to:

- References to `FolderChange` and `TypeChange` in `TCustomFileDialog` class.
- Procedures `OnFolderChangeEvent` and `OnTypeChangeEvent` in `TFileDialogWrapper` class.
- The whole `TFileDialogEvents` class.

Although these changes were tested with Delphi 10.3.3 the solution should be similar for Delphi 10.3.1 and even more recent versions as this unit hasn't changed much along time.